# Is Elastic Net my best choice for finding sparse linear models in correlated features?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, linear-model, lasso, linear

I have a linear regression problem, 1000 data points,  but with **36** correlated features, those features are very highly correlated. And I know the ground truth must be linear.

I know Lasso would give me **random** results in such strongly linearly correlated settings. I have google a lot, it seems that Elastic net is something at least can give me a certain solution for every run.

Is there any better suggestions?

### Extra credit

Is there any method can give me all the **combination** of acceptable features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Net (that is a combination of Lasso and Ridge Regression) would be a good choice. Although the Lasso part in it might still select a sample of the features. Lasso selects 1 variable at random from a set of highly correlated variables, so it's not completely at random. You should play around with the $\alpha$ value to determine how many variables you want in your final model from the Elastic Net.

Also, you could try Group Lasso, which allows you to pre-specify which variables belong in which group, although this requires a little more work.

Comment: Thanks. But the key point is that I don't have ANY knowledge on which variables belong to the same group. Although for simple problem I can show but my goal is to do complicated problems in which pre-grouping variable is impossible. So group lasso or sparse Group lasso is not for me, indeed I spent a whole afternoon yesterday because I was misleaded by its name...I thought it could automatically select all the groups for me.

Comment: Then the Elastic Net is a good choice, try different values for $\alpha$ and $\lambda$, using CV and such to find the best ones.